# Listing out prime dividers of numbers given

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a problem on one interactive website and after trying the code with some examples of mine it seems to work, however, if I load it on the website, it says there's a wrong answer which leads me to think that there is one (or multiple) cases where my code fails to execute correctly but I can't seem to find such.

The problem is:

For each given whole positive number return its prime divisors in ascending order. The first line of the input (a natural number) is how many numbers we want to check. In the following lines are numbers greater than 2. For each number return (in one line) that number, a semicolon and its prime divisors in ascending order. Each divisor has to appear only once.

Example:

```
 2
 12
 1024
```

Should return

```
12: 2 3
1024: 2
```

My C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int prime_check(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int no_of_inputs;
    cin >> no_of_inputs;
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_inputs; i++)
    {
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        cout << val<<": ";
        for (int i = 2; i < val; i++)
        {
            if (val% i == 0)
            {
                if (prime_check(i) == 1)
                {
                    cout << i<< " ";
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Nothing. It's just that interactive website saying 'Wrong Answer' but it won't give me examples of inputs where the answer was incorrect.

Comment: As @nicomp subtly suggested. Find a case where your code fails, step through the code line by line, keeping a look at your input, and notice what you expect to happen vs what happens at each step - debug.

Comment: You provided a colon. It asked for a semicolon.

Comment: @Cortex Thank you for saying 'subtly' !

Comment: don't rely on some website to find errors in your code. Eventually it is your duty to test your code and make sure it is correct. 'Wrong Answer' is useless as test result, you need to write your own tests where you can inspect what exactly is going wrong

Comment: You forgot to test with prime numbers.

Comment: What are the limit integer number in input? what are the memory limit?

Comment: Problem solved. It failed with prime numbers and you suggested. Thank you to everyone who contributed.

Comment: You could be have to take care the execution time limit

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you that use the algorithm the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for you selected all prime and assigned the prime divisores to each number in the range:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> primeDiv;
bool noPrimes[MAXINTERGER] = {0};
void criba(){
    for(int i = 2; i <= MAXINTERGER; ++i)
        if(!noPrimes[i])
            for(int j = 2; i*j <= MAXINTERGER;j++){
                noPrimes[i*j] = true;
                primeDiv[i*j].push_back(i);
            }
}
```

and finally in your main the prime divisor for `val` are `primeDiv[val]`, you can iterate and print the values. Be carefull with the presentation error!

---

> ### Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm on action
>
> [image: Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm]